# Word 2007 Ctrl+Alt+1 hotkey

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007, hotkeys

As far as I can remember, Microsoft Word used to switch to Heading 1 when you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, Heading 2 when you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, and etc. But I have noticed it doesn't do that anymore.

Is this something in Word, or could it be another program conflicting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I forgot I had set up Winamp to use Ctrl+Alt+1 to Ctrl+Alt+5 to rate songs. I guess this was conflicting. I removed the global hotkeys from Winamp and it works again.

Answer (score 2):

Strange. According to Microsoft's [Quick Reference Card - Up to speed with Word 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/training/Training.aspx?AssetID=RP100664491033):

> Shortcuts that start with the CTRL key
>   (for example, CTRL+C for copy or
>   CTRL+ALT+1 for Heading 1) remain the
>   same as in previous versions of Word.

This is also carried out by a quick test I did with Word 2007 - the hotkey still works.

Answer (score 1):

I have a german edition of ms word and I have to use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for *heading 1*

Also, you can assign your preferred shortcut for a style (which you can store in your normal.dot file). Maybe, you accidentally changed it.